# Как пишется ASP.NET MVC-приложение, которое обращается к Web API?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Например, есть некоторое Asp.Net Web Api приложение и нужно написать `ASP.NET MVC` приложение, которое бы дергало API и отображало информацию пользователю на сайте.

Нашел пример на Metanit.com и там работа с `WEB API` осуществляется через запросы, которые дергаются напрямую из `JavaScript`, а далее ответный JSON рисуется в интерфейсе. Только в таком стиле можно работать с `WEB API` или есть какие-то другие варианты?

Например, в WCF можно прямо в контроллере создать клиент, что-то сделать и выплюнуть во вьюху все.

Comment: Хотя... вроде, нашел пример http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consume-web-api-get-method-in-aspnet-mvc . Тут через webclient идет обращение к API, далее оно десериализуется и пуляется во вьюху. Правильно ли так работать?

Comment: Web API он чей - ваш или чужой? Если чужой, то да, обращаемся к нему с помощью WebClient/HttpClient/WebRequest.

Comment: А если мой....?

Comment: ASP.NET проекты WebAPI и MVC одинаковы. Они отличаются только тем, что api возвращает данные в виде json (или xml, csv...), а mvc отправляет эти данные во вюьху, где они преобразуются в html. То есть нужно добавить необходимые View в каждый контроллер и всё. Ну, ещё как-то пути разрулить.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, т.е вы предлагаете в WEpAPI проект добавить вьюхи. Получается, что сам WebApi проект будет самодостаточным и меть веб-морду, а те кто захочет работать через API будут слать REST запросы напрямую контроллерам?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @Хм... А такая практика нормальна?

Comment: Не знаю. Подождем, может подтянутся другие разрабы ASP.NET и выскажутся.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87529/discussion-between-iluxa1810-and-alexander-petrov).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, мне кажется, что так не совсем нормально делать, так как мы связываем напрямую веб API и морду. Если по отдельности делать независимо, то так на мой взгляд гибче.

Comment: @iluxa1810 не совсем понял ваш вопрос, но во первых сейчас уже все делают на .net core, во вторых в современной Full-st разработке для фронта используют Angular или React которые отвечают за фронт логику и разметку а back часть т е сервер выплевывает данные в JSON. Это работает намного быстрее тк разметка будет много весить и будет тормозить ваше приложение, в то время как вам на фронт нужно передать условный объект user вы будете передавать целую html страницу, это не практикуется уже очень давно (в нормальных конторах)